# Which layout for building a keyboard consisting of buttons

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to make a keyboard just like the default android keyboard. It's supposed to be consisting of buttons and to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnckC.png

I already learned how to create custom buttons from image resources and it looks like this right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcAC0.png

As you can see from the first image the keys are not vertically synchronal. I don't really know which layout to use for this.
What's the best way to realize this ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can use gridview.

Comment: For spacing use marginLeft attribute.

Comment: I tried the gridLayout and added buttons from A-F just to understand how this works. So I tried to make it look like this: http://fs03.androidpit.info/userfiles/6056531/image/tt.png    Currently the result is: http://fs01.androidpit.info/userfiles/6056531/image/a.PNG       As you can see there's a space now between letter A and B and the distance between those two rows is way to big. This last matter is caused by the layout_gravity value in my xml file. So i tried to change it to an dp-value but eclipse was giving me an error. Here is my xml-file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JWhsFEjh